# How do you UNION with multiple CTEs?

Tags: sql-server, union, common-table-expression

How do you use `UNION` with multiple `Common Table Expressions`?

I'm trying to put together some summary numbers but no matter where I put the `;`, I always get an error

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    dbo.Decision_Data
UNION
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT Client_No)
FROM    dbo.Decision_Data
UNION
WITH    [Clients]
          AS ( SELECT   Client_No
               FROM     dbo.Decision_Data
               GROUP BY Client_No
               HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
             )
    SELECT  COUNT(*) AS [Clients Single Record CTE]
    FROM    Clients;
```

I appreciate in the example above I can move the **single** CTE to the beginning, but I have a number of CTEs I'd like to `UNION`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If you are trying to union multiple CTEs, then you need to declare the CTEs first and then use them:

```
With Clients As
    (
    Select Client_No
    From dbo.Decision_Data
    Group By Client_No
    Having Count(*) = 1
    )
    , CTE2 As
    (
    Select Client_No
    From dbo.Decision_Data
    Group By Client_No
    Having Count(*) = 2
    )
Select Count(*)
From Decision_Data
Union
Select Count(Distinct Client_No)
From dbo.Decision_Data
Union
Select Count(*)
From Clients
Union
Select Count(*)
From CTE2;
```

You can even use one CTE from another:

```
With Clients As
        (
        Select Client_No
        From dbo.Decision_Data
        Group By Client_No
        Having Count(*) = 1
        )
        , CTE2FromClients As
        (
        Select Client_No
        From Clients
        )
    Select Count(*)
    From Decision_Data
    Union
    Select Count(Distinct Client_No)
    From dbo.Decision_Data
    Union
    Select Count(*)
    From Clients
    Union
    Select Count(*)
    From CTE2FromClients;
```

[WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: My bad ... I want to UNION multiple CTE's

Comment: @SteveC - In short, you need to declare all the CTEs you want to use in your final expression first and then use them in your union query.

Comment: Thanks. The use of a comma to declare multiple CTE's was what i was missing.

Answer (score 17):

You can do it like this:

```
WITH    [Clients]
          AS ( SELECT   Client_No
               FROM     dbo.Decision_Data
               GROUP BY Client_No
               HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
             ),
        [Clients2]
          AS ( SELECT   Client_No
               FROM     dbo.Decision_Data
               GROUP BY Client_No
               HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
             )
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    Clients
UNION
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    Clients2;
```

Comment: My bad ... I want to UNION multiple CTE's

Comment: This wont work as you are using the Clients CTE after declaring Clients2 CTE.Its out of referrence

Comment: @AnandPhadke - This works fine, I cannot understand why you say it won't work

Comment: @DaveShaw -- Yeah I was thinking of having some select statements between CTEs.If we have any sql statements between CTE's then it wont work.This case yes it will work.

Comment: Did you use any tool or extension to format your code that way? I like it and hadn't seen it before.